# Angular: singleton service vs mat dialog problem

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to use my singleton service on Mat Dialog but as far failed to do so. New service instance is created when opening dialog for the first time and I'm getting undefined on userList at *user-options-provider.service.ts*. The only helpful information I could get online about it, is that the Mat Dialog is created out of scope for this service. So is there any way to use my singleton service in Mat Dialog component?

*user-options-provider.service.ts*

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserOptionsProviderService {

  private userList: Array<User>;

  private userListObs = new BehaviorSubject<Array<User>>(this.userList);

  constructor(private boardsProviderService: BoardsProviderService) {  }

  setUserList(id: string): void {
    this.userList = this.boardsProviderService.getBoard(id).userList;
    this.userListObs.next(this.userList);
  }

  getUserListObs(): Observable<Array<User>> {
    return this.userListObs.asObservable();
  }
}
```

*user-options.component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-options',
  templateUrl: './user-options.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-options.component.css']
})
export class UserOptionsComponent implements OnInit {

  userList: Array<User>;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,
              public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<UserOptionsComponent>,
              private userOptionsProviderService: UserOptionsProviderService) {

    this.userOptionsProviderService.getUserListObs().subscribe((users: Array<User>) => {
      this.userList = users;
    });

  }

  ngOnInit() { }
```

called and provided in *board.component.ts*

```
  onClickUserOptions(boardId: string): void {
    this.dialog.open(UserOptionsComponent, {
      data: {boardId}
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Link to a working StackBlitz [LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-fzvrum)

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserOptionsProviderService {

  // private userList: Array<User>; is undefined.
  // private userList: Array<User> = []; is a blank array.
  // Below is the correction.
  private userList: Array<User> = [];

  // new BehaviorSubject<Array<User>>(this.userList) is then 
  // new BehaviorSubject<Array<User>>(undefined)
  // you want to have this.userList be and []
  // new BehaviorSubject<Array<User>>([])
  private userListObs = new BehaviorSubject<Array<User>>(this.userList);

  constructor(private boardsProviderService: BoardsProviderService) {  }

  setUserList(id: string): void {
    this.userList = this.boardsProviderService.getBoard(id).userList;
    this.userListObs.next(this.userList);
  }

  getUserListObs(): Observable<Array<User>> {
    return this.userListObs.asObservable();
  }
}
```

> One issue at a time. Now in your component do this...

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-options',
  templateUrl: './user-options.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-options.component.css']
})
export class UserOptionsComponent implements OnInit {

  userList: Array<User>;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,
              public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<UserOptionsComponent>,
              private userOptionsProviderService: UserOptionsProviderService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userOptionsProviderService.getUserListObs().subscribe((users: Array<User>) => {
      this.userList = users;
    });
}
```

> And you still need to call the servcie.setUserList(id) to set the array. Where do you plan on doing that? Either in the constructor of the service or in the component. Where will you do it? That is the method that sets the array to an actual array of users.
>
> You could also do this based on your code...

```
  // In the board.component.ts file
  // You need to call setUserList() before you create the dialog
  // because when you create the dialog it pulls the subscription,
  // which in the initial state is a blank [];
  // You call the service, which loads the array, and by the time
  // the dialog loads it should be in the subscription.
  // Do this first to see that it works, then I'll send a stack blitz 
  // showing another way. In your case, the dialog is tied to the service
  // I think maybe you could give it a little more freedom.

  onClickUserOptions(boardId: string): void {
    this.UserOptionsProviderService.setUserList(boardId);
    this.dialog.open(UserOptionsComponent);
  }
```

Comment: That's just fix for getting undefined. But still I'm getting blank array, and I want to use data held by service.

Comment: edit: I am setting this in board.component.ts after user authentication. I have already tried to put this onInit but still when opening dialog, another (unset with this setUserList) instance of service is being created.

Comment: Can you add to your question, the steps you would expect things to occur? Like, 1. userList is empty [] and component is NOT in dom. 2. dialog is clicked and then array is full [1,2,3]. etc...

Answer (score 0):

Passing the service worked.

*board.component.ts*

```
  onClickUserOptions(): void {
    const s = this.userOptionsProviderService;
    this.dialog.open(UserOptionsComponent, {
      data: {s}
    });
  }
```

*user-options.component.ts*

```
export class UserOptionsComponent implements OnInit {

  s = this.data.s;
  userList: Array<User>;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,
              public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<UserOptionsComponent>,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.s.getUserListObs().subscribe((users: Array<User>) => {
      this.userList = users;
    });
  }
}
```

Thank you very much :)